# SQL LIKE operator not showing any result

Tags: sql-like

I am trying to return all of the project numbers that start with a particular year code (e.g. '19').  Project numbers are formatted in '19-0100' format always.  However, the code runs but returns no results

I've looked at some similar posts and tried the solutions suggested; still doesn't return any results.  Data in the projectnumber column is formatted as short text with no extra spaces before or after numbers as one other post suggested.

```
SELECT ProjectNumber, client, ProjectTitle 
FROM ProjectNumbers 
WHERE ProjectNumber LIKE '19%'
```

This should give me a list of all the project numbers that start with 19 (e.g. it should return **19**-0100, **19**-0101... but not **18**-0100), but  get nothing at all.

I've also tried '19-%', '19-____', '19-%', and '19_____'. All have the same result.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which database software are you using?

Comment: from "short text" I assume Access. in which case  [use `*` not `%`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931)

Answer (score 0):

Basic check to be done, Is there a corresponding data in the dB? 
Please verify by modifying the where clause in accordance with an existing data. 
This is something that used happen to me in my initial days.

Comment: In the table this is referencing, I have a projectnumbers column with 19-0100 thru 19-0104.  If I take out the WHERE clause completely it works fine...